# 403 error with a 301 redirect in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a rewrite rule for one of my pages. This rule is supposed to be for a specific single URL only hence the "static-ness".

```
RewriteRule ^picks/categorizedPicks/126$ search/?catalogue=11&module=20 [NC,L,R=301]
```

This rule is a permanent redirect with the `R=301` flag.

The redirect works fine without the R=301 flag but gives a 403 error with it.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: as I know, for non-external redirects you should not put that in rewriterule. because it adds file localtion on server to request URI and that makes an error!

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^picks/categorizedPicks/126$ /search/?catalogue=11&module=20 [NC,L,R=301]`

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [R] flag, your substitution should be a URL not a relative path.